# I am stack with 'THIS' javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that i want to execute when scroll end.
So when i scroll "div 1" i want to execute the code with "div2". The problem is that this code have .scrollLoad and some "this" in the code. If i change "this" with "div2" the code don't work. So when i scroll to div1 I want "this" to recognize the div2.

```
$( '#div2' ).scrollLoad({


            url : 'load_more_categ.php', //your ajax file to be loaded when scroll breaks ScrollAfterHeight
            type: 'POST',
            data : '',


            start : function() {
                $('<div class="loading"><img src="bigLoader.gif"/></div>').appendTo(this);
            // you can add your effect before loading data
            },

            ScrollAfterHeight : 95,         //this is the height in percentage after which ajax stars

            onload : function( data ) {
                $(this).append( data );

                $('.loading').remove();



            }, // this event fires on ajax success

            continueWhile : function( resp ) {
                if( $(this).children('li').length >= 100 ) { // stops when number of 'li' reaches 100
                    return false;
                }
                return true; 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, it will make it easier for use to help you. Also linking to the plugin you use (i.e. `scrollLoad`) would help as well.

Comment: Which `scrollLoad` plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becuase the javascript is decalred within the scrollload handler of #div2, `$(this)` is #div2.

```
$( '#div2' ).scrollLoad({
```